# jQuery Template is not binding properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following html:

```
<table>
    <thead>(something here)</thead>
    <div id="templateContainer"></div>
    <tfoot>(something here)</tfoot>
</table>
```

I have appropriate jquery JSON code to bind the template properly into the `#templateContainer` and data are also successfully binded. But here's the problem, after binding the data, the `#templateContainer` doesn't appear to where it is supposed to be, in fact it turned out to be (in dev tool):

```
<div id="templateContainer"></div>
<table>
    <thead>(something here)</thead>
    <tfoot>(something here)</tfoot>
</table>
```

Can I know what may have caused the above misplaced template? Thanks

**Edit**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function filterList() {
        var filter = 25;
        PageMethods.getList(filter, OnSuccessFilter);
    }

    function OnSuccessFilter(data) {
        BindTemplate(data[0]);
    }

    function BindTemplate(data) {
        $.get('/UserControls/User/template.htm', function (template) {
            $('#templateContainer').empty();
            data = eval('(' + data + ')');
            jQuery(template).tmpl(data).appendTo('#templateContainer');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not valid markup.  What is your intent here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `<div>` inside a `<table>` that way. The `<div>` will appear outside the table as you can see. It's because the syntax is incorrect.

You have to replace your wrapper (`<div id="templateContainer"></div>`) with `<tr>'s` and `<td>'s` so it'll be an acceptable HTML table.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Changed `<div>` to `<tbody>` and it's working flawlessly!

Comment: Nice. Good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest a `<div>` element in a `<table>` element, it is invalid markup. It's not JavaScript that's moving your `<div>` outside your table, it's your browser attempting to correct the mistake.

If you can better explain what your intentions are, I can try to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Changed `<div>` to `<tbody>` and it's working flawlessly!

Comment: Note that technically tbody should come AFTER tfoot in your markup.